# i have no idea what is wrong with this script!!I am comparing x with y here

Tags: linux, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
read x
read y
if [ $x -lt $y ] then                                 
echo "X is less than Y"
fi
if [ $x -gt $y ] then
echo "X is greater than Y"
fi
if [ $x -eq $y ] then
echo "X is equal to Y"
fi
```

Comment: What was the input? What output did you expect and how was it different from the actual one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error on your script. Put 'then' below the 'if', as follows:

```
if [ $x -lt $y ]
then
echo "X is less than Y"
fi

if [ $x -gt $y ]
then
echo "X is greater than Y"
fi

if [ $x -eq $y ]
then
echo "X is equal to Y"
fi
```

And the script will work :-).